# Why $E[y|x;\theta]$ can be thought as $h_\theta (x)$, the hypothesis, in Generalized Linear Model?

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

I am learning Standford CS229 [lecture note1](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf).
In **9 Constructing GLMs** part,

> To derive a GLM for this problem, we will make the following three
>   assumptions about the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ and about
>   our model: ......
>    Given $x$, our goal is to predict the expected value of $T(y)$ given $x$. In most of our examples, we will have $T(y) = y$, so this means we would
>   like the prediction $h(x)$ output by our learned hypothesis $h$ to 
>   satisfy $h(x) = E[y|x]$.

I didn't get a well understanding on why hypothesis $h$ need to satisfy $h(x) = E[y|x]$ when we have $T(y) = y$.
It will be appreciated if anyone could give some hints or explanations.